# text-align:start not apply just at IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, alignment

I'm trying to set my input left using text-aling. It works at Chrome, FF, etc, but just not in IE11

Am I using this property wrong? Or is just a IE bug?

Here is a fiddle with the following code: http://jsfiddle.net/uykykfsb/

```
<html>

<style type="text/css">
.a {
    border: 1px solid red;
    text-align: center;
}   
.b {
    border: 1px solid green;
    width: 400px;
    height: 200px;
    text-align: start !important;
}
</style>

<body>
    <div class="a"> 
        <div class="b" >
            <input type="text"></input>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `text-align: start;` is not supported on Internet Explorer - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-align

Comment: This isn't a bug.  Using "start" is not something that is actually supported by CSS (http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/text.html#alignment-prop).  It is a pseudo-value that has become acceptable in many browsers to use the default preference of the user.  IE, does not support this pseudo-value.

Comment: Interesting... I had set "start" because I saw it was the default value that the chrome applied when nothing was set

Comment: That is just how Chrome lists it.  The actual default does what you have explained you want.  Using "start" is basically telling to to align to whichever side is considered the beginning.  Using "end" does the exact opposite.  On a left-aligned page, "start" aligns to the left while "end" aligns to the right.  On a right-aligned page, it's the exact opposite.  In most cases, you want to specify values for multiple browsers to ensure compatibility.  So, be sure to look-up what you can use in each browser.  The less you have to put, the better. ^^

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`text-align: start` is currently not supported in Internet Explorer https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-align#Browser_compatibility

Comment: Just to add `text-align: left` worked for my use case.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest to keep using `text-align: start;` but with a fallback to `text-align: left;`.

```
.b {
    border: 1px solid green;
    width: 400px;
    height: 200px;
    text-align: left;
    text-align: start;
}
```

This way, modern browser will overwrite `text-align: left;` with `text-align: start;`. And browsers that do not support the `start` value will just keep using the `left` value.

Comment: Why add the override, though?  Won't all browsers recognize `text-align: left`?

Comment: Yes, but it also allows the browser to decide how to best align text based on the user's LTR or RTL preference. In my case I used it because it was already used in a class of the CSS framework I used and I just added the fallback to fix it for IE.